# Stimulus JS, modal doesn't close after clicking on background

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, stimulusjs

I copy-paste code from another view(for example: about-page), where modal works just as I expect. But for some reason in this view (for example: contact-page) I can only close modal by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>. If I click on the background, then modal move a little to the right side.

```
%div
  -if annotations.empty?
    %p.text-2xl.text-primary-600.mt-2.text-center= t('views.doctor_portal.annotation_form.no_annotations')
  -else
    .text-center.text-xl.text-primary-600= t('views.doctor_portal.annotation_modal.header')
    .flex.flex-row.flex-wrap.border-2.border-gray-700.w-full.h-max.overflow-y-auto.justify-center.rounded{style: 'max-height: 14rem'}
      - annotations.each do |annotation|
        %button{data: { controller: "modal", "data-modal-allow-background-close" => "true" } }
          .flex.flex-col.w-52.h-max.border-2.border-primary-500.m-1.p-1.rounded{ "data-action" => "click->modal#open", :href => "#" }
            / Modal Container
            .hidden.animated.fadeIn.fixed.inset-0.overflow-y-auto.flex.items-center.justify-center{ data: { action: "click->modal#closeBackground keyup@window->modal#closeWithKeyboard", "modal-target" => "container", "modal-disable-backdrop" => true }}
              / Modal Inner Container
              .max-h-screen.w-full.max-w-lg.relative{ :style => "z-index: 9999;"}
                / Modal Card
                .m-1.rounded.shadow-2xl.bg-white.p-5
                  .text-center.text-xl.text-primary-500= t('views.doctor_portal.annotation_modal.note')
                  .text-center.p-2=annotation.content
                  .text-center.text-xs.-mb-5= t('views.doctor_portal.annotation_modal.press_esc')
            %div.text-center
              - if I18n.locale == :en
                #{l annotation.created_at, format: '%B %d %Y'}
              - else
                #{l annotation.created_at, format: '%d %B, %Y'}
            %div.text-center #{annotation.content[0..19]}(...)
:css
  #modal-background{
    display: none;
  }
```

EDIT:
**package.json**

```
 "stimulus": "^2.0.0",
  "stimulus_reflex": "3.4.1",
  "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat",
  "tailwindcss-stimulus-components": "^2.1.1",
```

**application_controller.js**

```
import { Controller } from 'stimulus'
import StimulusReflex from 'stimulus_reflex'

/* This is your ApplicationController.
 * All StimulusReflex controllers should inherit from this class.
 *
 * Example:
 *
 *   import ApplicationController from './application_controller'
 *
 *   export default class extends ApplicationController { ... }
 *
 * Learn more at: https://docs.stimulusreflex.com
 */
export default class extends Controller {
  connect () {
    StimulusReflex.register(this)
  }

  /* Application-wide lifecycle methods
   *
   * Use these methods to handle lifecycle concerns for the entire application.
   * Using the lifecycle is optional, so feel free to delete these stubs if you don't need them.
   *
   * Arguments:
   *
   *   element - the element that triggered the reflex
   *             may be different than the Stimulus controller's this.element
   *
   *   reflex - the name of the reflex e.g. "Example#demo"
   *
   *   error/noop - the error message (for reflexError), otherwise null
   *
   *   reflexId - a UUID4 or developer-provided unique identifier for each Reflex
   */

  beforeReflex (element, reflex, noop, reflexId) {
    // document.body.classList.add('wait')
  }

  reflexSuccess (element, reflex, noop, reflexId) {
    // show success message
  }

  reflexError (element, reflex, error, reflexId) {
    // show error message
  }

  reflexHalted (element, reflex, error, reflexId) {
    // handle aborted Reflex action
  }

  afterReflex (element, reflex, noop, reflexId) {
    // document.body.classList.remove('wait')
  }

  finalizeReflex (element, reflex, noop, reflexId) {
    // all operations have completed, animation etc is now safe
  }
}
```

Comment: we need some of your Javascript in order to help you. are you using the `stimulus-components` library for the modal controller?

Comment: @AidanMiles  I am not sure. I used something someone did and it worked. I don't know JavaScript myself. I have edited my question, maybe now there will be something useful there